# Tool to generate feedback based on test results

Tags: grading, tools

My mom is a tutor and she was hoping for some software to help her speed up her grading process. Currently, she has her students take a test and she needs to generate something for the student with what they need to work on.

For instance, the student takes a test and they get questions 3 and 4 wrong. Question 3 is on long division and question 4 is on exponents. Ideally, she would be able to put in what questions the student got wrong and get something in a presentable format she can email to the student and their parents:

> Areas to work on:
>
> - Multiplying exponents
> - Long division with numbers greater than 3 digits

Is there any software out there that can do something like this?

Thanks,

Eric

Answer (score -1):

A possibility is to use a vlookup() in an Excel sheet.

Have a list with the q numbers and areas - every q number entered will return the area to a pre-set reporting area.

Put this together just for fun - you can edit and play as you wish:
[image]

Just enter the question numbers in cells E3:E12, leave un-needed ones blank and it sorts it out.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I made a Google Sheets form similar to that where it aggregates all the questions wrong and generates a report + emails it out (using a custom script). I wasn't sure of a good way to store records of student's performances, which is why I was thinking that an enterprise solution might be the way to go. Do you have any ideas on storing records per student?

Comment: Let us hope the downvoter can show us something better, created by their own hand of course... But somehow I won't hold my breath.